# How do I deal with a dictionary of objects that is constantly changing in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, discord

The current situation:
I'm using Discord's API to retrieve a dictionary of member objects in my server. This dictionary is constantly changing in size as new members join and old members leave.

I currently have a program that has a run time of around 30 minutes and accesses this dictionary of member objects so it's guaranteed that this dictionary changes size as I iterate over it in my program; this causes an error in my for loop. I also can't seem to `deepcopy` this dictionary;

> TypeError: can't pickle dict_values objects

Any ideas of how I can work around this problem?

Code:
`for i in members:
    do something;` <--- while this is happening members changes in size
Trying this also doesn't work:
    temp = copy.deepcopy(members)
This is what the dict is: dict_values([`<discord.member.Member object at 0x1094b3268`>, `<discord.member.Member object at 0x1094b32f0`>, etc

Comment: Sounds like you may need to protect it with a mutex. What is changing it? Your code or somethign else?

Comment: Just throwing out something here: Put it in a database maybe?

Comment: `TypeError: can't pickle dict_values objects` uh, so what exactly are you doing that is giving you this error. This would happen with something like `pickle.dumps(some_dict.values())`

Comment: Turn the dictionary into a list of keys and assign it to a new variable. Then iterate through the keys. and then access the dictionary one at a time. Or you could use `dict.keys()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I ended up solving my problem:
 `temp = copy.deepcopy(list(members))`